# Tem como posicionar mensagem do required?

Tags: html, css

tenho o seguinte **html**

```
<ul class="pagamento-metodos">
   <li class="pagamento-metodo paypal">
     <input name="payment_methods" type="radio" id="paypal" value="paypal" required>
     <label for="paypal"></label>
   </li>
   <li class="pagamento-metodo pagseguro">
     <input name="payment_methods" type="radio" id="pagseguro" value="pagseguro">
     <label for="pagseguro"></label>
   </li>
   <li class="pagamento-metodo boleto">
     <input name="payment_methods" type="radio" id="boleto" value="boleto">
     <label for="boleto"></label>
   </li>
</ul>
```

No `CSS` fiz assim:

```
input[type=radio] {
    left:-100px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Com isso, consigo "**esconder**" os **Rádio Buttons** e estilizar com mais **CSS** claro, os **labels** para ficar no lugar dos **rádio búttons** e ainda posso ter o pleno funcionamento do **required**.

O problema é que, como posicionei os **radio buttons** fora do ecrã e, por conseguinte, sua mensagem também vai ficar e não vai ser vista.

É possível alterar apenas o posicionamento da mensagem do **require** para cima do **label** e manter o próprio **radio button** escondido?

Comment: Se bem entendi você quer esconder apenas as rodinhas dos radios certo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bastará um `opacity: 0;` nos inputs e mudar a posição das labels para irem para o lugar deles, eles continuaram lá, mas não ocuparam espaço, e mesmo com o label você conseguirá seleciona-lo porque ele está presente. Veja este jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/goqkkfz8/1/

Comment: Não é isso não.
O detalhe é fazer a mensagem do require aparecer na posição correta mesmo com o input radio deslocado da posição.
Fazendo disoplay:none, a validação passa direto e vai para o próximo campo ou submete o formulário,
Estou conseguindo selecionar normalmente, o problema é a validação de campo sem preencher. Não gostaria de usar JS. Apenas o require do html5 mesmo.

Comment: Já entendi, você quer que quando der o erro de required, apareca na label e não no input certo?

Comment: Na verdade eu quero é que o aviso apareça. Pode ser até no input mesmo. O problema é que o input está posicionado fora do ecra, o que leva a mensagem de erro também para fora não sendo possível sua visualização. Nesse caso, eu quera trazer para o ecrã apenas a mensagem de erro do input mas manter ele fora do ecrã. Não sei se será possível isso!

Comment: @CarlosRocha Tentou `opacity:0`?

Comment: @CarlosRocha Veja o meu js fiddle, atualizei

Comment: exato: opacity:0. Muito Obrigado! Só o opacity:0 já resolveu. http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/